# jquery spacing letters onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**without click**

```
<a class="single-item__cover">
```

**After click**

```
<a class="single-item__cover active play">
```

Here after click link change to active play.so how to query on click if only single-item__cover active play is active only

**my javascript**

```
const $featured =$('a.single-item__cover.active.play');

$featured.on('change', function() {
    console.log('working fine');




    
});
```

Comment: `$('.single-item__cover').on('click', function() { this.addClass('active', 'play')})`

Comment: addClass('active', 'play') single-item__cover active play working fine.but my question is single-item__cover active play to onclick

Comment: Not really understanding your question or your current comment. I really just guessed at what you were trying to say. 

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript snippet demonstrating how you can change the classes of some input elements (checkboxes before c, d, e) affecting their status being watched by an `.addEventListener("change"...)` listener. The key point and difference to OP's code is, that I add the listener to the `document.body` but limit the action to those "changed" elements that have at least the `.active` class set. You can make it more strict by checking both classes with an `&&` condition, like

```
if (ev.target.classList.contains("active") && ev.target.classList.contains("play"))
```

```js
const ctoe=[...document.querySelectorAll("input")].slice(2,5);
document.querySelector("button").onclick=()=>ctoe.forEach(e=>{
 e.classList.toggle("active");
 e.classList.toggle("play")
})
document.body.addEventListener("change",ev=>{
 if (ev.target.classList.contains("active"))
  console.log(ev.target.nextSibling.textContent+" changed.")
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="single-item__cover active play"> a active<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="single-item__cover"> b<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="single-item__cover"> c *<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="single-item__cover"> d *<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="single-item__cover"> e *<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="single-item__cover"> g<br>
<button>toggle c-e active</button>
* can be active or not, controlled by button.
```

Answer (score 0):

That because the event created before the elemen class exist.

for dynamic element/attribute you can attach the event to the body, but it will make the event double.

```js
$('a.single-item__cover').on('click', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  $(e.target).addClass('active play');
  console.log('play');
})

$('body').on('click', 'a.single-item__cover.active.play', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  $(e.target).removeClass('active play');
  console.log('stop');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="single-item__cover">play</a>
```

a better way is to use toggle strategy

```js
$('a.single-item__cover').on('click', (e) => {
  let a = $(e.target);
  e.preventDefault();
  a.toggleClass('active play');
  if ((a).hasClass('play')) {
    a.text('Stop')
  } else {
    a.text('Play')
  }
})
```

```css
.active.play {background: yellow;padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" class="single-item__cover">Play</a>
```